# How to use CSS class/id to change other classes attributes?

Tags: css, class, html, hover

So I want to :hover on an element and I want the hovering to change an attribute of another class. How do I do it? I want to hover on to a button and it to change other div's display to display: block. I use only HTML and CSS.

Comment: What does your HTML look like? What CSS have you tried?

Comment: I have not tried anything, because I don't know how to change another classes attributes in another class.. EDIT: To clarify, I don't even know what to try.

Comment: Without a bare example of the code (even just the markup is a good start) you're trying to use so far, you're unlikely to find much help. Just so you know, however, it's unlikely you can get what you're looking for, as you shouldn't nest a div in a button object, so you won't be able to use parent-child relationships in your CSS to trigger a switch. You'll need to use some Javascript in all likelihood to get this to happen.

Answer (score 10):

You are limited by css, but there are possibilities with css selectors. I've made you a jsfiddle with a possible solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/6rT3Q/

**CSS:**

```
.item1:hover ~ .item3 {
    background-color: red;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="item1">
    Hoverable item
</div>

<div class="item2">
    Dummy item
</div>

<div class="item3">
    Item to change
</div>
```

Here the `~` tells to look for succeeding elements. If you want the immediate next element you can use `+`.

More info about selectors:

http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/

Comment: .li:hover ~ .crs {
 display: block;
}
It still does not work.. 
.crs {
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: 170px;
 display: none;
 background-color: #0080C0;
 color: white;
 border-radius: 5px;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100px;
}

Comment: Could you show me what your html looks like? Because with `~` you are limited as to where the item to change can be placed.

Comment: <div id="menu">
   <a href=""><div class="li">Etusivu</div></a>
   <a href=""><div class="crs" id="crs_dp">1. kurssi</div></a>
   <a href=""><div class="li">Biologia</div></a>
   <a href=""><div class="li">Maantieto</div></a>
   <a href=""><div class="li">Historia</div></a>
   <a href=""><div class="li">Yhteiskuntaoppi</div></a>
   <a href=""><div class="li">Uskonto</div></a>
   <a href=""><div class="li">Terveystieto</div></a>
   <a href=""><div class="li">Filosofia</div></a>
   <a href=""><div class="li">Psykologia</div></a>
  </div>

Comment: crs (course) class is the one that is hid and should be displayed a block when hovered over li

Comment: From what I see I don't think you understand how to use lists. Maybe you could read this: [HTML Lists](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp) or follow a tutorial on lists [Tutorial on unordered lists](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-y2Yjd/0/5?curriculum_id=50579fb998b470000202dc8b).

Comment: I'm not using any lists, that li is just a class name.

Comment: That's a bit odd but okay. Using my method it's not possible to use the html you posted, because both the .li's and the .crs are inside an element. Try something like this though: http://jsfiddle.net/XJ6Nz/1/

Answer (score 5):

Without using JS, you can change a child node of the element being hovered. For example if you had:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">Content</div>
</div>
```

You could use the below code to change the .box properties:

```
.container:hover .box
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, but it doesn't work. I'll try in javascript now.

Comment: see @wouthoekstra's answer for targeting other elements using selectors

Comment: Is it possible to reference more than one class?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `javascript` for this. Put your button in a div and use the following:

```
document.getElementById("buttonDiv").onmouseover = function() {
    document.getElementById["divToHide"].style.display = "block";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you would use Javascript.  For example with jQuery you could do:

```
$( "#hoveredElement" ).mouseover(function() {
   $( "#otherDiv" ).css("display", "block"); //or just use .show() if it is
                                             //initially hidden
});
```